# NaN value always returned from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
  var s = parseFloat(txtTotal.value, 10);
if (isNaN(s) || txtTotal.value == 0) {
    fncAlert("Please enter amount greater than 0");
    return false;
}
```

The above code is always RETURNING S AS NaN. Any Help ?

Comment: share value of `txtTotal`

Comment: In text box, I am entering 5000

Comment: That's fine.... but where are you defining `txtTotal` ??

Comment: your `txtotal` might not be `an numeric value`

Comment: 'var txtTotal = $("#txtNet").val().toUpperCase();'

Comment: remove `toUpperCase()`

Comment: probably .value does not exist and returns undefined

Comment: try `var s = parseFloat(txtTotal, 10);`

Comment: same error @Sankar Raj

Comment: also, make sure `$("#txtNet").val()` returns the number in a tring representation.

Comment: Thank you ** Pranav **.. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like as follows as you are taking value in ***txtTotal*** 
variable

First remove `toUpperCase()`, then use:

```
var txtTotal = $("#txtNet").val();
var s = parseFloat(txtTotal, 10);
if (isNaN(s) || txtTotal == 0) {
   fncAlert("Please enter amount greater than 0");
   return false;
}
```